# SQL Server : creating a view using two tables with the same columns vs using 1 table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two machines that both return the same data, I'm curious as the pros/cons of using 2 tables vs 1 table with a "machine" column when creating a view.

For instance 1 table

```
;WITH Pre AS (
  SELECT X, EquipmentID, JoinID
  FROM OneTable
  WHERE EquipmentID=1
),
Post AS (
  SELECT X, EquipmentID, JoinID
  FROM OneTable
  WHERE EquipmentID=2
)

SELECT Pre.X AS 'PreX', Post.X 'PostX', Post.X-Pre.X AS 'DeltaX'
FROM Pre INNER JOIN Post ON Pre.JoinID = Post.JoinID
```

vs having 2 tables (pre and post) already separated and only using the last select statement. Is there an established practice in place for this type of data?

There could obviously be a better way than my CTE for 1 table as well that I don't know about. Thank you.

Edit* With this example, I'm doing 1 delta; but what I'm actually looking for is deltas for every data column .  The actual data is normalized into 4 tables and the main data table will be putting data into it about 3 times a second and get around 1M(ish) rows probably.  Just to help with the vagueness.

Comment: This question is basically unanswerable since you are asking for a general case which depends on many other things -- the rest of the data model -- use cases -- etc etc

Comment: There's not even benefits of using one vs the other?  I can't figure out how to word it for google.  I could post my entire view but figure that's bad practice.  The data are actually many columns (all of which are the same for both machines) that are normalized over 4 tables.  And I'm looking for the deltas for every single column.

Answer (score 1):

The question is a bit too broad as a result the answer is the dreaded “It Depends”.

The main advantage of keeping your equipment data in one table is that it simplifies your table structures and makes it easier to maintain your database.

However, if the data log rate from your underlying equipment is very high and you have to store large amount of data you may be better of keeping your tables separate purely from a performance standpoint.

You can still get the best of both worlds by creating a partitioned view on the two tables. The partitioned view will give you a single view but with the performance benefit that comes with two tables. I would only recommend this approach with high volume data otherwise keep your table structures simple (in other words stick with one table).
Following simple talk article gives a good example of how a partitioned view works:

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/sql-tools/sql-server-partitioning-without-enterprise-edition/

Answer (score 0):

No sure i totally undersdand the problem, but alternative to JOINing two queries to the same table is GROUP BY pivoting method.

```
SELECT 
    max(case EquipmentID when 1 then X end) AS 'PreX',
    max(case EquipmentID when 2 then X end) AS 'PostX',
    max(case EquipmentID when 2 then X end) - max(case EquipmentID when 1 then X end) AS DeltaX
  FROM OneTable
  WHERE EquipmentID in (1,2)
  GROUP BY JoinID
  HAVING max(EquipmentID) <> min(EquipmentID)
```

Provided (JoinID,EquipmentID) contains PK of OneTable it must produce the same result. Arguably it may have better perfomance.